# Using Liouville's theorem to conclude that if $|f(z)| \le |\sin^3 z|$ then $f$ is a multiple of $\sin^3 z$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and suppose that $
|f(z)| \leq |\sin^3(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbf{C}$. Show that $f(z) = \lambda \sin^3(z)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I have a typo it should be $|f(z)| \leq ...$

Comment: Yes, your example definitely works! however, it is not a proof of the problem :(

Comment: Yes, this is an application of Liouville. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: I think that you should consider $f(z)/\sin^3(x)$ and show that this function is entire. My problem is that I am not sure how to show that the zeros of $sin^3(z)$ occur with multiplicity at least 3 in $f(z)$

Comment: @Clayton Yours is not a counterexample, because it corresponds to $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Ah, correct....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a theorem that if a function $g$ is holomorphic in a (deleted) neighborhood of a point and bounded in that neighborhood, then $g$ has only a *removable* singularity. (And analogously, if $|g(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to z_0$, then $g$ has a pole there; the remaining case is that $g$ has an essential singularity.) In this case $g$ has a holomorphic extension across that point.

Following your comments, this deals with the issue of concluding that $f$ has zeros of multiplicity at least $3$ at every zero of $\sin^3 z$. So setting $g(z) = f(z) / \sin^3 z$ leads to a holomorphic function with a discrete set of removable singularities. Replacing $g$ with an entire extension and invoking Liouville completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, in general if an entire function is bounded above by an entire function then the function is a multiple of the bound?